# API for Live Captions on Windows

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, desktop-application

I'm build a Win Universal App with capabilities to watch live captions of the lecture which student is currently watching or attending in person. I'm looking for a built-in free solution to do audio to text operations.

macOS have the Speech lib https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech , which we're going to use, but cannot find a similar on Windows. Found docs on Windows.Media package, but cannot figure out if it actually has audio2text api or just commands recognition https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechrecognition?view=winrt-22621

Maybe someone has experience with building such kind of capabilities on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use the [Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition?view=winrt-22621) API for speech recognition not only with the commands recognition.

You could make a simple test with the official Speech Recognition Sample here: [SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis). Just remember to enable the Online speech recognition (Settings -> Privacy -> Speech).